# Using collections with webapi asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, automapper, dto

I'm having some difficulties adding a collection to a webapi controller:

I have a class "Publications":

```
public class Publications
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int RoomMates { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AddDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PublicationFilePath> PublicationFilePaths { get; set; }

}
```

And a class "PublicationFilePath" containing all filepaths linked to the publications from the class mentioned above:

```
public class PublicationFilePath
{
    public int PublicationFilePathId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public FileType FileType { get; set; }
    public virtual Publications Publication { get; set; }
}
```

I created the following DTO's:

```
 public class PublicationsDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }        
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AddDate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PublicationFilePath> PublicationFilePaths { get; set; }

}

public class PublicationsDetailDTO
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int RoomMates { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AddDate { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PublicationFilePath> PublicationFilePaths { get; set; }

}
public class PublicationsFilePathsDTO
{
    public int PublicationFilePathId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

At last this is the GET method from my webapi controller using Automapper:

```
// GET: api/PublicationsAPI
    public IQueryable<PublicationsDTO> GetPublications()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Publications, PublicationsDTO>());

        var publications = db.Publications.Include(p => p.PublicationFilePaths).ProjectTo<PublicationsDTO>();

        return publications;
    }
```

However when running the code and requesting the api I get the following error:

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessageExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace />
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Type System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.PublicationFilePath_A0D9D29395534E1AFC4F8E51FE41FB7B06CBE02E84BBB7D3C75B4E5DE116D45D met gegevenscontractnaam PublicationFilePath_A0D9D29395534E1AFC4F8E51FE41FB7B06CBE02E84BBB7D3C75B4E5DE116D45D:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies wordt niet verwacht. U kunt dit probleem omzeilen door DataContractResolver te gebruiken of door typen die niet bekend zijn op statische wijze aan de lijst met bekende typen toe te voegen, bijvoorbeeld door het kenmerk KnownTypeAttribute te gebruiken of door ze toe te voegen aan de lijst met bekende typen die aan DataContractSerializer worden doorgegeven.
</ExceptionMessage>
```

I think I'm having problem with the Icollection, please advise on how to continue here.

Comment: It seems you didn't map PublicationFilePathDTO. So it is using the Entity Framework PublicationFilePath.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Ruard, could you indicate where I forgot to map the PublicationFilePathDTO? I'm quite new at this. Thank you!

Comment: In both PublicationsDTO and PublicationsDetailDTO you map to ICollection<PublicationFilePath> (the EF object) instead of ICollection<PublicationsFilePathsDTO>.

Comment: Thanks again Ruard, this indeed makes sense! How should I change the GET method from the Publications api controller? I need to add two mappings I guess and I'm not sure on how to do this.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Why would you have to change the GET method?

Comment: When I leave it like described above I get the following exception: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Missing map from Go_CoHousing.Models.PublicationFilePath to Go_CoHousing.Models.PublicationsFilePathsDTO. Create using Mapper.CreateMap<PublicationFilePath, PublicationsFilePathsDTO>. So it seems an additional mapping is necessary here.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: I am really not into automapper, so I cannot help you. But I think you should check the automapper configuration. It think you need to add an additional mapping there.

Answer (score 0):

I can agree with Ruard it's an Automapper mapping issue.
You're only mapping Publications to PublicationsDTO.
You should also map PublicationFilePath to PublicationFilePathsDTO.
(Also note you pluralised the word Path to Paths in the DTO)

Configuring nested mappings in AutoMapper is explained in [their Wiki-section](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Nested-mappings).

Hope this helps you out.

Greetings
William